# Why can this unbound variable work in Python (pyquery)?

Tags: python, variables, pyquery

The code is from the guide of pyquery

```
from pyquery import PyQuery
d = PyQuery('<p class="hello">Hi</p><p>Bye</p>')
d('p').filter(lambda i: PyQuery(this).text() == 'Hi')
```

My question is `this` in the 3rd line is an unbound variable and is never defined in current environment, but the above code still works.

How can it work? Why it doesn't complain `NameError: name 'this' is not defined`?

It seems that something happens at https://bitbucket.org/olauzanne/pyquery/src/c148e4445f49/pyquery/pyquery.py#cl-478 , could anybody explain it?

Comment: Thanks, I've never heard of PyQuery. Definitely going to try and use it.

Comment: Same here. Never knew about PyQuery before, sounds interesting ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done via Python's `func_globals` magic, which is

> A reference to the dictionary that holds the function’s global variables — the global namespace of the module in which the function was defined.

If you dive into PyQuery code:

```
def func_globals(f):
    return f.__globals__ if PY3k else f.func_globals

def filter(self, selector):
    if not hasattr(selector, '__call__'):
        return self._filter_only(selector, self)
    else:
        elements = []
        try:
            for i, this in enumerate(self):

                # The magic happens here
                func_globals(selector)['this'] = this

                if callback(selector, i):
                    elements.append(this)

        finally:
            f_globals = func_globals(selector)
            if 'this' in f_globals:
                del f_globals['this']
        return self.__class__(elements, **dict(parent=self))
```

Comment: Thanks, BasicWolf. But what's the meaning of `for i, this in enumerate(self)`, why would that be a loop to set the value of `func_globals(selector)['this']`?

Comment: Well, enumerate creates a sequence of [(index, element)] out of an iterable (and PyQuery class is iterable as a subclass of `list`). So, `i` is the index of an element and `this` refers to an element stored in the PyQuery object. The best way to understand how PyQuery works in-depth, is to dive into its code.

Answer (score 1):

Others have correctly point out how `this` is defined inside that lambda you are talking about.

To elaborate a bit more, try out the following code:

```
>>> def f():
...     print f_global
... 
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: global name 'f_global' is not defined
>>> f.__globals__['f_global'] = "whoa!!" #Modify f()'s globals.
>>> f()
whoa!!
```

This is exactly what is happening there. [On line 496, you would see the following code](https://bitbucket.org/olauzanne/pyquery/src/c148e4445f49/pyquery/pyquery.py#cl-496):

```
for i, this in enumerate(self):             #this is the current object/node.
     func_globals(selector)['this'] = this  #func_globals returns selector.__globals__
```

Answer (score -2):

This doesn't throw a NameError because the variable might exist at the time the actual function is called.

```
>>> f = lambda i: some_non_named_var
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
NameError: global name 'some_non_named_var' is not defined
```

The above does not error until you call the function that you've stashed away. In the example code you showed, they are manually setting a variable called `this` in the `func_globals` before calling the lambda `selector` function.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? It might not be as complete as some of the other answers, but it still demonstrates exactly what is happening..